# Combobox Selected Item

Tags: java

Here is my array of Strings :

```
String[] selection = { "0 + 0", "0.88 + 0.21", "-0.21 + 0.77", "-1.23 + 0.03" };
```

I then create a JComboBox:

```
    JComboBox<String> jcb = new JComboBox<String>(selection);
    jcb.addActionListener(new ComboListener());
```

Here is the ActionListener :

```
public class ComboListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox<String>) e.getSource();
        String selection = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        String[] parts = selection.split(" + ");
        System.out.println(parts[0]);
        System.out.println(parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Here's what is printed out when I select an option, say 0.88 + 0.21:

```
0.88 + 0.21
```

With the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at GUI$ComboListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:140)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone got any idea where I'm going wrong? My logic of splitting up the string seems to be fine. Many thanks;

Comment: I am not so sure the split works. If in doubt always write a small code with a specific string and regex applied and confirm the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as parameter. But `+` is a special regexp character. So you need to escape it:

```
String[] parts = selection.split(" \\+ ");
```

Another solution would be to use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] parts = selection.split(Pattern.quote(" + "));
```

---

```
String[] selection = {"0 + 0", "0.88 + 0.21", "-0.21 + 0.77", "-1.23 + 0.03"};
for(String s : selection){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(" \\+ ")));
}
```

Successfully prints:

```
[0, 0]
[0.88, 0.21]
[-0.21, 0.77]
[-1.23, 0.03]
```

Comment: blessings to you, my son.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception points out, the split doesn't work the way you intended (thought it would):

```
selection.split(" + ");
```

The problem is that split takes a regular expression so you need to escape the `+`

```
selection.split(" \\+ ");
```